# How to hide Tax Inc in the product page

Tags: magento-1.9

I just attached what i'm trying to hide from the product page, and that's is the following:

http://prntscr.com/bg41va

Comment: Easy way would be hide from css.

Answer (score 0):

By default, on product list and product details pages on the frontend the prices of products are displayed without tax. If you want to, you can show the prices with the tax included or you can show both the price prior taxation and the price with the tax included. To do this, log in to the admin panel of your Magento and go to `System menu>Configuration>Tax` button in the Sales section on the `left>Price Display Settings panel` on the right.

When you expand the panel `Price Display Settings` you'll see a couple of options. By default, the option `Display Product Prices In Catalog` is set to `Excluding Tax`. To show prices with `tax included` just set the option to `Including Tax` and `click on the Save Config button`. From the same option you can also select Including and Excluding Tax. In this case two prices will be shown for each product in the catalog; the first one will be the base price without any tax and the other one will be with tax included.

[For more see here.](http://magentoexpertforum.com/showthread.php/13758-Display-product-prices-in-the-catalog-with-and-without-tax-in-Magento)